# First tap on UITableView ignored after deleteRowsAtIndexPaths

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

My UITableView has a collection of cells. Swiping a cell causes a Remove button to appear.  Tapping this Remove button causes the following code to be executed:

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
[self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];
[self.itemList removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

This correctly causes the cell to be removed from the list. However, when I tap on one of the remaining cells in the UITableVIew to select it, this tap is ignored (i.e. tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath is not called). If I tap a second time, then it works correctly (i.e tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath is called).

It does not matter which cell I tap after the delete and it doesn't matter how long I wait after the delete, the first tap after the delete is always ignored and the second tap after the delete is successful.

Based on various stackOverflow answers, I have tried:

- setting `self.tableView.editing = NO;` after the delete
- calling `[self.tableView reloadData];` after the delete
- calling `[self.tableView reloadSections:indexSet withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];` after the delete
- calling `[self.tableView beginUpdates];` before the delete and `[self.tableView endUpdates];` after the delete
- doing all of the above at the same time

None of the above have helped; the first tap after the delete is still always ignored.

UPDATE:
I also added the `[self.itemList removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];` code to the code snippet above.
My datasource delegate methods look like this:

```
-(NSInteger) numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return self.itemList.count;
}
```

The code snippet above is being called in the doDelete method in response to a button tap (`[self.deleteButton addTarget:self action:@selector(doDelete) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];`)

UPDATE #2: Based on Lyssa's comments, I have tried the following: I removed all references to our custom Delete button and our swipe gesture and then added this code to our UITableView delegate:

```
-(BOOL) tableView:(UITableView*)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return YES;
}

-(void) tableView:(UITableView*)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        [self.itemList removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];
    }
}
```

That does work - I can now delete rows and the next tap does work correctly.  However, this removes our custom look and feel for our table cell, which was the purpose of our custom code in the first place. Perhaps I should be looking at using the above methods and customizing the Delete button instead (I have done some looking and not found a good answer yet).

Comment: Do you decrease count from numberOfRowsInSection: after you remove the cell.

Comment: did you update the datasource of your tableview, remove the data object of your deleted cell?

Comment: Where have you put the deleteRowsAtIndexPath?

Comment: I keep an NSMutableArray of elements, so in addition to deleting the row from the tableVIew, I am also calling `[self.itemList removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row]`.

Comment: I have updated the text of my issue based on your questions

Comment: From what you've said it seems like you're creating your own delete button and showing it on swipe? TableViews have this built in using `canEditRowAtIndexPath` and `commitEditingStyle`. Although I'm not sure why the way you're doing it would then ignore the first tap.

Comment: Yes, we are creating our own delete button.  I have updated the text of my issue based on your feedback.

Comment: Can you provide the code that presents the delete button?  Do you disable the ability to touch other cells when delete is present on one?

Comment: The code to present the delete button is in the `handlGesture` method of our MatchCell class (`MatchCell : UITableViewCell`) and is is done by setting `self.deleteButton.hidden = NO;` and then animating the alpha value of the the background views from 1.0 to 0. We do not prevent touches in other cells, but instead we keep track of which cell has a visible delete button and if a delete button appears in another cell, we hide the delete button and unhide the other views in the previous cell.

Comment: Maybe provide a screenshot of how your custom cells look in comparison to just doing it the standard way

Comment: You say the first tap is ignored, does the tableview still scroll or is that ignored aswell?

Have you implement didSelectCellAtIndexPath and if so does it get called when the first tap is ignored?

If not, try making sure you haven't disabled userInteraction on the cell's themselves or the tableView. Sounds like you need to post some more of your code in here for anyone to help you out more

Comment: How do you add your cell? Where do you add your button and its target-action? How do you hide/show your `deleteButton`? Please paste more code because my local code works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all who provided answers or comments to my question.  Your comments helped me track down the problem.

It turns out that we were implementing `tableView:shouldHighlightRowAtIndexPath` and we were returning NO for the first call after a delete and then returning YES from then on.  This is the reason the first tap was ignored.  Our full offending code was this:

```
-(BOOL) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView shouldHighlightRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (self.currentPath) {
        [self resetSelectedCell];
        self.currentPath = nil;
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

This code was provided to prevent more than one delete button from being displayed at once, but we were not resetting self.currentPath correctly after a delete.  We are now setting self.currentPath to nil after a successful delete and the code works correctly.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that when you use swipe-to-delete only the row you swipe enters edit mode.

And the first tap is ending editing mode for that row:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didEndEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
}
```

you can solve it by setting editing mode

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        [self.itemList removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [self.tableView setEditing:NO animated:YES];
    }
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: Downvoting because from [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDataSource/tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath:): "You should not call `setEditing:animated:` within an implementation of this method. If for some reason you must, invoke it after a delay by using the `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` method."